# How to Stream the Desktop and make it Accessable via URL?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, rtmp, flowplayer, windows-server

I'd like to Stream my Servers Desktop and make it public via example.com/stream

The Stream should include both Video and Audio.
The Server is Win 2008 using zwamp for Apache etc.
As of the Player, anything goes. I was thinking about Flowplayer.

Is there any easy step by step tutorial?
Every Tutorial I found was not really made for my scenario.
If there is any Tutorial which will definitely work for me, please feel free to point me towards it.

Much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried something like this? http://www.maximumpc.com/article/how-tos/how_livestream_your_games_web

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by downloading Microsoft's Windows Media Encoder, and do a "screen broadcast", where your server's desktop will be broadcasted. You could get the streaming link to your server's desktop once you start Windows Media Encoder.

Hope this helps.